Problem with nouveau driver and Ubuntu 24.04
I'm having a problem on Ubuntu 24.04. After a fresh installation, I notice that there are graphical bugs appearing in Gnome.
My config is as follows:
kernel : 6.8.0_36-generic
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
2x Intel cores 2 duo T9550 @ 2,66ghz
3,8 giga RAM
NVIDIA Geforce 9600M GT (rev a1)

Menus and listmenu are often invisible (the elements appear when hovering the cursor) or twinkle. This bug is present in gnome-control-center, nautilus but also in the gnome scanner application.
In the gnome control center the list of wallpapers or theme colors is not displayed and twinkle.
gnome-software also encounters the same type of problem.
Sometimes the desktop freezes completely and I have to do a hard reboot (even though ssh responds well).
I installed kde via apt install kubuntu-desktop. and I encounter much fewer problems with KDE applications.
But even under kde, gnome applications have bugs. On the Kde side only the system monitoring application is not displayed correctly. sddm is also unusable. I have to stay on gdm3.
When I start grub with the nomodeset parameter there are no more problems.
The problem appears both under X and Wayland
Here are the logs that I was able to recover before a freeze or when displaying wallpapers under Gnome.
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872181+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 0 - Unknown CUDA fault at address 00201c0e00
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872182+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 0 - e0c: 00000000, e18: 00000ff2, e1c: 00000000, e20: 00000000, e24: 09030000
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872185+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 1 - Unknown CUDA fault at address 00201caa00
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872202+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 1 - e0c: 00000000, e18: 00000ff2, e1c: 00000000, e20: 00000000, e24: 09030000
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872203+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: 00200000 [] ch 22 [001dc12000 gnome-control-c[20738]] subc 3 class 8297 mthd 15e0 data 00000000
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872216+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 0 - Unknown CUDA fault at address 00201c2800
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872218+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 0 - e0c: 00000000, e18: 00000ff2, e1c: 00000000, e20: 00000000, e24: 09030000
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872219+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 1 - Unknown CUDA fault at address 00201ca000
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872221+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 1 - e0c: 00000000, e18: 00000ff2, e1c: 00000000, e20: 00000000, e24: 09030000
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872222+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: 00200000 [] ch 22 [001dc12000 gnome-control-c[20738]] subc 3 class 8297 mthd 15e0 data 00000000
2024-07-09T10:34:32.872224+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped write at 00201ca000 on channel 22 [1dc12000 gnome-control-c[20738]] engine 00 [PGRAPH] client 0b [PROP] subclient 09 [LOCAL] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]

Here are logs retrieved during display problems under kde:
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166274+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped write at 00201bb200 on channel 9 [1efe6000 plasma-systemmo[12057]] engine 00 [PGRAPH] client 0b [PROP] subclient 09 [LOCAL] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166276+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 0 - Unknown CUDA fault at address 00201b0c00
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166278+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 0 - e0c: 00000000, e18: 00000ff2, e1c: 00000000, e20: 00000000, e24: 09030000
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166280+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 1 - Unknown CUDA fault at address 00201bb400
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166282+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_PROP - TP 1 - e0c: 00000000, e18: 00000f02, e1c: 00000000, e20: 00000000, e24: 09030000
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166284+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: 00200000 [] ch 9 [001efe6000 plasma-systemmo[12057]] subc 3 class 8297 mthd 15e0 data 00000000
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166286+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped write at 00201b0c00 on channel 9 [1efe6000 plasma-systemmo[12057]] engine 00 [PGRAPH] client 0b [PROP] subclient 09 [LOCAL] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166288+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: magic set 0:
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166290+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr:  00408904: 20097d01
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166292+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr:  00408908: 00000000
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166293+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr:  0040890c: 40000430
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166295+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr:  00408910: 00000000
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166297+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_TEXTURE - TP0: 00000003 [ FAULT]
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166299+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: magic set 1:
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166301+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr:  00409904: 20097f01
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166302+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr:  00409908: 00000000
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166304+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr:  0040990c: 40000430
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166306+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr:  00409910: 00000000
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166308+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_TEXTURE - TP1: 00000003 [ FAULT]
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166310+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: 00200000 [] ch 9 [001efe6000 plasma-systemmo[12057]] subc 3 class 8297 mthd 15e0 data 00000000
2024-07-10T11:30:05.166321+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped write at 00201b5000 on channel 9 [1efe6000 plasma-systemmo[12057]] engine 00 [PGRAPH] client 0b [PROP] subclient 09 [LOCAL] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
2024-07-10T11:30:14.420438+02:00 xxxx kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (3934 > 3933), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000

I also spotted these logs when using gnome:
2024-07-10T11:10:03.914954+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv84_xuc00f failed with error -2
2024-07-10T11:10:03.914968+02:00 xxxx kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: vp: unable to load firmware nouveau/nv84_xuc00f

2024-07-09T10:18:50.496002+02:00 xxxx gnome-shell[12508]: DING: (gjs:13017): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:18:50.484: GFileInfo created without standard::is-hidden
2024-07-09T10:18:50.498934+02:00 xxxx gnome-shell[12508]: DING: (gjs:13017): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:18:50.484: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1632 (g_file_info_get_is_hidden): should not be reached
2024-07-09T10:18:50.499189+02:00 xxxx gnome-shell[12508]: DING: (gjs:13017): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:18:50.484: GFileInfo created without standard::is-backup
2024-07-09T10:18:50.499330+02:00 xxxx gnome-shell[12508]: DING: (gjs:13017): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:18:50.484: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1654 (g_file_info_get_is_backup): should not be reached
2024-07-09T10:18:50.499646+02:00 xxxx gnome-shell[12508]: DING: (gjs:13017): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:18:50.484: GFileInfo created without standard::is-symlink
2024-07-09T10:18:50.500417+02:00 xxxx gnome-shell[12508]: DING: (gjs:13017): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 10:18:50.484: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1676 (g_file_info_get_is_symlink): should not be reached


The problem therefore seems to be on the nouveau driver. Unfortunately the graphics card is too old to be compatible with a proprietary Nvidia driver.
Note that the problem appears in the live session before installation, but this problem was not present on version 23.10 of Ubuntu.
Do you know what I can do?

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 24.04 screen glitches on gnome apps after install. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I resolved the problem by doing this.
In a terminal run :
sudo nano /etc/environment

to edit the file, then, add :
GSK_RENDERER=gl 

to the end of the file.

ctrl+x to save and confirm with Y or O.

Finally logout and reopen thesession.
It seems that adding this option fixes a lot of bugs on old graphics cards
